# Ansible - Access role variable of variable programmatically

Tags: ansible

My question was maybe not complete enough. 
Here is what I'm actually trying to do :

I have a role containing the informations regarding the keystore/ password for these keystore than some other roles might want to use.

The directory structure looks like this :

```
/roles/
    keystore/
        tasks/
            main.yml
        vars/
            main.yml
            vault.yml
    app1/
        defaults/
            main.yml
        meta/
            main.yml
        templates/
            app1.properties
        tasks/
            main.yml
```

in keystore/tasks.main.yml, I have a task to include the vars from the vault file :

```
- name: "Include vault variables"
  include_vars: "vault.yml"
```

in keystore/vars/main.yml, I have this :

```
keystore_1:
  path: /path.to.the.keystore_1
  password: "{{ vault.keystore_1_password }}"
keystore_2:
  path: /path.to.the.keystore_2
  password: "{{ vault.keystore_2_password }}"
```

In keystore/vars/vault.yml, I have (encrypted) this:

```
vault:
  keystore_1_password: password1
  keystore_2_password: password2
```

in app1/meta/main.yml, I reference the keystore role as a dependency :

```
dependencies:
  - { role: keystore }
```

In app1/defaults/main.yml, I have, in a variable, the name of the keystore I want to use, by default, for this app ( I want to be able to change this depending on the environment):

```
 keystore_to_use: keystore_2
```

In app1/templates/app1.properties I want to be able to get the correct path and password for the specified keystore.

```
keystore.path= {{ vars[keystore_to_use].path }}
keystore.password= {{ vars[keystore_to_use].password }}
```

This is working fine for the path but not for the password where I get this instead of the password :

```
{{ vault.keystore_2_password }}
```

-- Original Question :

I'm having trouble accessing role variables programmatically in ansible.
Here is what I'm trying to do.

I have a vars/main.yml file containing something like this :

```
test_variable: "{{test1.var1}}"
test1:
  var1: "{{finalVariable}}"
finalVariable: finally
```

In my template, I'd like to use something like `vars['test_variable']` and I was expecting to receive `finally`.
Instead, I receive `{{test1.var}}`

Any idea how I should handle this?

Comment: Where do you receive this?  Inside a template?

Are you sure you want to use role vars?  You might want default vars instead (defaults/main.yml).  These variables are evaluated later and substitution seems to work better.

Comment: I receive this inside of a template. I adapted my question to explain what I'm actually trying to achieve.

Comment: The vault variables are not loaded when the keystore role vars  are parsed and templated.  With this being the case you end up with two layers of variable jinja templating which doesn't work.

Comment: I don't understand why this ```keystore_2.password``` is working then. 
How do you think I should try to solve my problem ?

Answer (score 0):

Order matters. In your first line `test1.var1` is not yet defined. When you define `var1`, again, `finalVariable` is not yet defined. Reverse the order and that should work.

But I agree with @Petro026's comment. It looks like you're trying to overload variables and in that case simply define your default values in `defaults/main.yml`. If that's not what you're trying to do, it might be worth to explain your goal a little more.

Comment: I adapted my question to explain what I'm actually trying to achieve.